# How to run useEffect only once when multiple dependencies change at a same time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am using a useEffect hook with two depencies as follows:

```
useEffect(() => { ..... }, [apiData, currentMeasurements]);
```

**Note that, the apiData is obtained through useLazyQuery of apollo/client.**

Now upon save (say, saving or submission of form), two dependencies change at a time i.e apiData is got and currentMeasurements are also set to new array using setState, (i.e, setCurrentMeasurements([])).

Since API call takes time, React is executing useEffect once when currentMeasurements are set, and once again when I get the API response back.

But this isn't the expected behavior. This is causing rendering the old values on the screen for the first time when useEffect is rendered (because of changes in currentMeasurements) and after a couple of seconds, new data is rendered (when useEffect again runs because we get newApiData).

**How to make useEffect run only when I get the API response back? or in other words, how to make useEffect run only when I get two dependencies ready to be passed in useEffect.**

Things I tried but didn't work:
Using setTimeOut (with custom time) for updating currentMeasurements, but this causes problems when API response is delayed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can save both dependencies as refs, and then check if both changed. If not do nothing. If it did, update the ref.

```
const changedRef = useRef({});

useEffect(() => { 
  if(changedRef.current.currentMeasurements !== currentMeasurements &&
     changedRef.current.apiData !== apiData) {
    
    ... // do something
    
    changedRef.current = {
      apiData
      currentMeasurements
    };
  }
}, [apiData, currentMeasurements]);
```

However, it's easier to use a breaking condition - ie if the length of `currentMeasurements` is 0, don't do anything inside the `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(() => { 
  if(currentMeasurements.length === 0) return;
  
  ... // do something

}, [apiData, currentMeasurements]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Compare their initial value, If any of them persist it then don't execute the side effect

```
useEffect(()=>{

if(currentMeasurements.length == 0 || apiData == InitialValue) return;

// do something with apiData and currentMeasurements

}, [apiData, currentMeasurements])
```